# Magento 2.1.1 Rest API Update price only

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

Trying to Change only the price of the products with PUT method.

HERE http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/Products/products.html#RESTAPI-Resource-Products-HTTPMethod-PUT-products--id

is stated that this is possible! But When i make a call with only the price in the product array i get a response like

```
    Array
(
    [message] => Invalid product data: %1
    [parameters] => Array
        (
            [0] => Invalid attribute set entity type
        )

)
```

So i add attribute set adn then i get the response

```
Array
(
    [message] => The value of attribute "name" must be set
)
```

On the magento link here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/Products/products.html#RESTAPI-Resource-Products-HTTPMethod-PUT-products--id

Says that this should be possible with no other params

> Enter only those parameters which you want to update.

Any ideas why is this happening?

the call i am using 
    PUT /rest/V1/products/:sku

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following rest PUT call:

```
/rest/V1/products/{SKU}
```

Passing the following json:

```
{
"product": {
  "price": 9.63,
  "extension_attributes": {
    "stock_item": {
      "qty": 63
    }
  }
 }
}
```

So you can update price and stock quantity with one single call. You can remove the extension_attributes value, if you only want to update the price.

**EDIT**

You will need a quotation mark for your price, like this below. I don't quite understand why because the price should be a **double** variable in the database.

```
{ 
    "product":{ 
        "price":"9.63",
        "extension_attributes":{ 
            "stock_item":{ 
                "qty":63
            }
        }
    }
}
```